# Getting error when running angularJs app in chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, google-chrome

Has anyone came across this error while running the app in chrome

```
> main.js:73532 RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
>     at String.replace (<anonymous>)
>     at Function.camelCase (https://localhost:8443/CustomerEngage-Account_Management/dist/js/main.js?v=1519715358157:18658:45)
>     at Function.css (https://localhost:8443/CustomerEngage-Account_Management/dist/js/main.js?v=1519715358157:24805:22)
>     at Object.get (https://localhost:8443/CustomerEngage-Account_Management/dist/js/main.js?v=1519715358157:24850:38)
>     at Function.css (https://localhost:8443/CustomerEngage-Account_Management/dist/js/main.js?v=1519715358157:24820:16)
>     at https://localhost:8443/CustomerEngage-Account_Management/dist/js/main.js?v=1519715358157:28460:13
>     at access (https://localhost:8443/CustomerEngage-Account_Management/dist/js/main.js?v=1519715358157:22318:15)
>     at jQuery.fn.init.jQuery.fn.(anonymous function) [as outerWidth] (https://localhost:8443/CustomerEngage-Account_Management/dist/js/main.js?v=1519715358157:28433:11)
>     at NavigationCtrl.adjustMenu (https://localhost:8443/CustomerEngage-Account_Management/dist/js/main.js?v=1519715358157:169828:71)
>     at NavigationCtrl.adjustMenu (https://localhost:8443/CustomerEngage-Account_Management/dist/js/main.js?v=1519715358157:169853:22)
> <div ui-view="" class="ng-scope" data-ng-animate="1">
```

Only the header is coming in the app rest data is not coming.
Any help will be appriciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you add code?

Comment: Please share the code. The error means you are calling something infinitely.

Comment: Seems like you are running into recursion in your code.

Comment: Which part of code should I add?

Comment: I am new to angularJS , thats why asking such silly question

Comment: main.js you are getting this error?

Comment: add your code please.